# What assumptions could a garbage collector for a pure, functional, eagerly-evaluated language safely make?

Tags: functional-programming, garbage-collection, jvm

Clarifying the question a bit:

Garbage collectors such as those used by the JVM involve a lot of complexity as a result of the nature of the languages they support. What simplifications would be afforded to a garbage collector purpose-built for a pure, functional, eagerly-evaluated programming language compared to say, the JVM garbage collector?

Comment: This is a very broad question which could probably fill an entire book. Can you narrow it down further?

Comment: Do you have any suggestions for ways it could be narrowed down?

Comment: No, not really. You're painting broad strokes here. I wouldn't even know where to begin.

Comment: I suppose if I knew how to narrow the question down, I wouldn't need to ask it in the first place. There is almost certainly some very concrete, high-level differences in what two GCs have to accommodate given the languages they support, and it is those specific differences I am asking about.

Comment: Worth to ask there: https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/garbage-collection

Comment: `pure, functional, eagerly-evaluated programming language` is there even such a thing?

Comment: Elm is one such language

Comment: Simplifications…not much. Optimizations…a lot.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'm barely an expert in functional languages design but when thinking about your question, immediately the following topics come to my mind:

- most probably it would be **generational GC**, at least I see no reason why it should not be. It could probably benefit from tuning to a large number of temporary objects
- no **write-barriers** - due to immutability it is not possible to create a reference from older object to newer one. No older-to-younger references mean no need for the remembered sets in case of generational GC, thus no write-barriers are necessary to manage them. This is a great simplification in my humble opinion.
- easier **safe-points** - due to the functional languages nature, function calls are much denser than in object-oriented programming. Even loops may be defined as recursive function calls. This should make implementing GC safe-points easier - for example, simply on each function entry. For example, read [this article](http://flyingfrogblog.blogspot.com/2012/03/gc-safe-points-mutator-suspension-and.html) as a reference.
- no **pinning** - if our hypothetical, pure functional language does not support native code cooperation, object pinning will not be necessary in case of compacting GC. This can greatly simplify its design.
- no **finalization** - object finalization probably would not fit into purely functional language. I feel it breaks referential transparency. And if we do not support native resources, one will not need it at the first place.